# Norm of covariant derivative via Riemannian metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces, smooth-manifolds

I am currently reading "Nonlinear analysis on manifolds: Sobolev spaces and inequalities" from Emmanuel Hebey and on page 21, he introduces the Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds. In there, he introduces the norm of the $k$-th covariant derivative:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. For $k$ an integer and $u\in C^\infty(M)$, $\nabla^ku$ denotes the k-th derivative of $u$ (with the convention $\nabla^0 u =u$). As an example, the components of $\nabla u$ in local coordinates are given by $(\nabla u)_i = \partial _i u$, while the components of $\nabla^2 u$ in local coordinates are given by
> $$(\nabla^2 u)_{ij} = \partial_{ij} u - \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial _k u.$$
> \begin{equation}
> |\nabla^k u|^2 = g^{i_1j_1} \ldots g^{i_kj_k} (\nabla^k u)_{i_1\ldots i_k} (\nabla ^k u)_{j_1\ldots j_k}.\label{1}
> \end{equation}

I am struggling to see why this actually defines a norm. In the case $k=1$, this follows from the fact that $g^{ij}$ is a positive definite matrix. My attempt to prove it was to look at the case $k=2$ where the right side has the following form:
$$g^{i_1j_1} g^{i_2j_2} (\nabla^2 u)_{i_1i_2} (\nabla ^2 u)_{j_1j_2}.$$
If I write this in matrix form, $A$ being $(\nabla^2 u)$ and $G$ being $g$, then this expression becomes
$$\text{tr}(GAG^\top A^\top),$$
where $G$ is symmetric, so $G= G^\top$, however $A$ isn't necessarily symmetric aswell. Due to that, this expression is **not** the same as
$$\text{tr}(GA A^\top G^\top),$$
which would simplify things a lot.
At this point I'm stuck and I don't know why this should define a norm for the matrix $A$. Any ideas for the case $k=2$ or even better the general case?

Comment: The trick here is to note that $G$, as a positive definite symmetric matrix, has a unique positive definite symmetric square root $R$. Now substitute $G = R^2$ into your formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Deane's clever solution for the case $k=2$, here is the similar proof for an arbitrary $k$:

We write $g^{i_lj_l}$ as $r^{i_l m_l}r^{m_l j_l}$, where $r$ is also positive definite and symmetric. Then, the initial expression becomes
\begin{align*}
&r^{i_1 m_1}r^{m_1 j_1}\ldots r^{i_k m_k}r^{m_k j_k} (\nabla^k u)_{i_1\ldots i_k} (\nabla ^k u)_{j_1\ldots j_k}\\
&= (r^{i_1 m_1}\ldots r^{i_k m_k} (\nabla^k u)_{i_1\ldots i_k})(r^{j_1 m_1}\ldots r^{j_k m_k} (\nabla^k u)_{j_1\ldots j_k} )
\end{align*}
In this form, we see that the expression is always non-negative. By a similar argument, we see that we have $|\nabla ^k u|^2 = 0 \iff \nabla ^k u =0$.